# how can select data from data base but different category and different data

Tags: php, mysql

how can select data from data base but different category and  different data

example data select :

sql="select * from newspaper";

and

sql="select * from vegetable";

how can select data from table same page

thank you

Comment: are you asking how in PHP you can have an HTML table with data in it from 2 sql tables ?

Comment: no ,retrieve data from  newspaper,vegetable  same page

Comment: just keep doing what you are doing, just extend it more. You're doing great

Answer (score 1):

If the datatypes of the corresponding columns are same, you could use an `union` to query from multiple tables/views. E.g. :

`select title,  manu_V,  manu_C,  manu_D,  yer_manu,  offr_oe
from table_1
[where clause]
**union**
cont_num, email,  catgy,  tit,  cat_grup, Estae_catagry
from table2
[where clause]`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to execute the two queries and output the data from the two arrays you get.

Comment: This should have been a comment instead.

Comment: Please use comment box for any suggestions. Thanks